# Is it possible the extrude some faces with correct geometry?

Tags: edit-mode

Back to my (infamous) mesh of a shed which has a great number of edges produced using loop cuts and the knife tool.
I tried extruding (by 0.025m so that they stand out from the adjacent faces) all the faces you see (in the image below) which I have applied a brown timber material to but some of the 'geometry' went wrong especially at the corners which were then not 'square' to the other faces.
I thought that I would give up as it's not all that important as the modelo will never be viewed up close BUT thought I would post the question just for the learning experience (it in fact it is possible).
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please highlight or zoom in the problem you're talking about? Extrusion seems to work fine...

Comment: Hi moonboots. I am only extruding (all) those faces which have had the brown wood material applied.  If I choose all those faces on one side at a time the corners don't look good. If I only choose the two faces which are at say one corner then the faces created on the side of them (intersecting with the face with the 'corrugated' face) is not at 90 degrees.    Please advise how you extruded all the faces with the brown wood material? Did you choose all of them together and the extrude or one at a time?   Forget about the tall vertical separate mesh which is the side door.

Comment: Oh. Maybe I should have selected 'offset even'. Is that what is required?

Comment: Is this just a question of holding Alt while extruding, or checking the 'Even Thickness' box in the operator? Does that make the difference you're looking for? Oops, overlapping comments..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> then *Extrude Faces Along Normals* and enable the *Offset Even* option in the *Operator Box*? But it won't give a good topology because the roof stick to the walls. You can do the opposite, select all the walls between the beams and extrude inwards with an *Extrude Faces Along Normals* as well:

[image]

Comment: Thanks moonboots. Yes it was the bad topology between the roof and the walls. The thought had occurred to me to extrude the walls between the beams inwards but I hadn't tried tha5t. Thanks again.